# Submiting a two page paper to a math journal

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics

I recently posted [my two-page paper](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Gaitanas_K/0/1/0/all/0/1) to arxiv and sent it to the editor of a good journal. The editor responded:

> "Your result is not substantial enough" and so it was rejected."

I cannot say that I totally disagree with the editor, the paper does not make any significant progress on number theory but I can't say that my paper is totally without value. It is the first time I have tried to publish a paper, and I am confused:

- Was my paper rejected because it is too short?
- Should I submit it to another journal?

I would really appreciate if someone gave me some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps you should discuss this with your advisor.

Comment: My research is related to number theory. _I do not want to sound harsh_, but the result you obtained doesn't look like anything breakingly new. I think that working with [the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), many master students would manage to derive these results if given as a homework, not to mention that the Wiki page contains a very small potion of the results on asymptotics of the prime counting function.

Comment: @tohecz you did not sound harsh but i am not talking about asymptotics in my paper.(this is the reason i thought it could draw some attention)Also some other "formulas for $\pi(n)$ are published.Why not mine?Also many results in mathematics could be proved from many master students if where given as homework but i think this kind of logic cancels the hole idea of publishing anything new.

Comment: [The formula from wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/9/d/49d8ee7e10fcb1b170b68a2a05cc4b3a.png) seems to be sufficient to get your result. What you do _is_ asymptotics, because you just say that some function is closer that `1/2` from another function infinitely often. Now tell me how that is not asymptotics. Sorry, just try to ask people at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) for a proof of your theorem, I believe that you'll get one in 10 minutes (unless people consider it completely non-interesting). If everything posted there was worth publishing, we would all be screwed.

Comment: (1) "Substantial" does not mean "Long". A short paper can make a substantial contribution if it gives deep insight. A long paper can make an negligible contribution if it says nothing new. (2) The general advice to publishing is "edit and try again". But the editing usually should reflect the comments from the editors and the referees in the letter of rejection. When the charge is that the result is not substantial enough, you either (a) agree, in which case you find a journal whose bar for publishing results has lower threshold for "substantial" or (b) disagree, in which case you edit...

Comment: ... the manuscript to include a discussion of why your result is substantial. (Literature review and comparison to other current works are heavily encouraged.)

Comment: @Willie Wong thank you very much!I will try this and get whatever possible i can to improve my paper.

Comment: Evaluating individual research papers isn't really on topic here, but here's a little information.  I like your formula, but unfortunately I don't think it's really novel or important enough to be published in a good journal.  There many journals out there, and it could certainly be published somewhere, but you probably wouldn't be happy with some of the papers that would be published alongside it.  Posting it on the arXiv means it will be archived and can already be cited.  Beyond that, you could publish it in a journal, but I don't see a strong scholarly or career argument for doing so.

Comment: @tohecz what i am trying to say is:Mills proved a result that is not so usefull in practice in an one page paper.http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183510803  I do not claim that my result is usefull in practice or that is a great theorem but i believe is something that should be mentioned.Am i wrong?Should it be "buried"?

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician thank you very much for your comments.Could you suggest some journals?I did not have the intention to post my paper for evaluation here really but i think it was necessary to give the link

Comment: I read once somewhere that Einstein's paper on 'E=MC^2' was only 3 pages long.

Comment: This might be appropriate to mention:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627736/interesting-but-short-math-papers
in particular there is a link to a super short paper:
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-02/S0002-9939-1972-0309047-X/S0002-9939-1972-0309047-X.pdf

Comment: @Squirtle Yes, this is a great paper you linked!Thank you for the encouragement!

Comment: Your link does not point to a paper, but to all your papers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am no expert in number theory, so I can't really help you with the last question (if you should submit your paper to another journal). However, it sounds like the editor stated the reason for rejection pretty clear: In his impression the results are not substantial enough. This is a valid (and frequent) reason for rejection. So in this respect you are in good company. If the editor did not state explicitly that he finds the paper "too short" than there is no reason to believe that this was the reason for rejection.

To get good feedback on how to proceed with your paper and your research you should **ask your advisor** (or find one).

Comment: i do not have any more an advisor i have graduated in 2010 and for some serious reasons i was out of research since then. I sent an e-mail to one of the proffesors that i used to have good connection but  he replied "my mother is in the hospital we will talk again after some days" etc (this happened before 6 months)I sen him the paper and told him to answer whenever he could (but he did not)